# integrating 2 lists and a data farme in RR

Tags: r, list, dataframe, integrate

Please could you advise on the R code I could use in order to do the    following operation :

1. I have 2 lists of "genome coordinates" : a list is composed by numbers that represent genome coordinates;

let's say list `N`:

```
n1    
n2    
n3    
n4
```

and a list `M`:

```
m1     
m2     
m3     
m4     
m5
```

2. and a dataframe `C`, where for some pairs of coordinates (n,m)    from the lists above, we have a numerical intensity;

for example:

```
n1; m1; 100 
n1; m2; 300
```

The question would be : what is the most efficient R code I could use in order to integrate the list `N`, the list `M`, and the   dataframe `C`, in order to obtain a dataframe with:

- list `N` as the columns names
- list `M` as the rows names
- the values in the cells of `N` * `M`, corresponding to the numerical values in the data frame `C`.

A little example would be :

```
     n1  n2  n3 n4 
m1  100  -   -   - 
m2  300  -   -   - 
m3   -   -   -   - 
m4   -   -   -   - 
m5   -   -   -   -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `spread` in the `tidyr` package, making sure to keep all values of n and m that appear in the two lists, even if they don't appear in C:

```
library(tidyr)
## Replicating the data
listN = list("n1","n2","n3","n4","n5")
listM = list("m1","m2","m3","m4","m5")
C = data.frame(n=c("n1","n2","n3"),m=c("m1","m2","m3"),I=c(100,300,400))
   n  m   I
1 n1 m1 100
2 n2 m2 300
3 n3 m3 400

## Defining factor levels of C using listM and listN, and keeping unused levels when doing the spread
C$n = factor(C$n,levels=unlist(listN))
C$m = factor(C$m,levels=unlist(listM))
res = spread(C,key="n",value="I",drop=F)
```

This returns:

```
   m  n1  n2  n3 n4 n5
1 m1 100  NA  NA NA NA
2 m2  NA 300  NA NA NA
3 m3  NA  NA 400 NA NA
4 m4  NA  NA  NA NA NA
5 m5  NA  NA  NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone has a cleaner way to implement the following, and I would be happy to know. Your data is not really MWE ready: see [How to make a great R Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). However, given the data "as-is" and assuming you don't really want the first row titled 'n1'. The following solution requires `reshape2` package:

```
N=c('n1','n2','n3','n4')
M=c('m1','m2','m3','m4','m5')
C=data.frame(
  X1=c('n1','n1'),
  X2=c('m1','m2'),
  C=c(100, 300)
)
```

We've defined the data as above. Now let's merge it together.

```
X = merge(N, M)
```

Let's add `NA`s to the `data.frame` so that it will be blanked when we define the items.

```
C$C <- NA

C$C <- C[which(C$X1 %in% N & C$X2 %in% M),'C']

D = merge(N, M, all=TRUE)
names(D) <- c('X1','X2')
names(X) <- c('X1','X2')

E = merge(D, C, all = TRUE, by=c('X1', 'X2'))

library(reshape2)
reshape2::dcast(E, X2 + C ~ X1, drop=FALSE, value.var='C')
```

Hopefully this will help you out until someone else can explain it a little better.

EDIT: Since @Lamia beat me to it, I compared the `system.time` values for the examples. . . and @Lamia's answer is 0.01 +/- 0.032 over ten reps on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

We could use a indexing method

```
m1 <- matrix(0, length(listM), length(listN), dimnames = list(unlist(listM), unlist(listN)))
m1[cbind(match(as.character(C$m), rownames(m1)), 
                  match(as.character(C$n), colnames(m1)))] <- C$I
m1
#    n1  n2  n3 n4 n5
#m1 100   0   0  0  0
#m2   0 300   0  0  0
#m3   0   0 400  0  0
#m4   0   0   0  0  0
#m5   0   0   0  0  0
```

#### data

```
listN <- list("n1","n2","n3","n4","n5")
listM <- list("m1","m2","m3","m4","m5")
C <- data.frame(n=c("n1","n2","n3"),m=c("m1","m2","m3"),I=c(100,300,400))
```